# Elasticsearch JavaScript Bulk Update

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch JavaSript Client v 8.1 having trouble using bulk update to update a group of documents.

My dataSource is an array like this:

```
const myDatasource = [
 {
   _id: "field_id",
   my_field: "new value 1"
 },
 {
   _id: "field_id",
   my_field: "new value 2"
 }
]
```

.. where "field_id" is the actual id and my_field is the field I want to update.

Ok so I want to use bulk operations to do this. Going by the example in the docs I have:

```
const result = await client.helpers.bulk({
  datasource: myDatasource,
  onDocument (doc) {
    
    return [
      { update: { _index: 'my_index', _id: doc._id } },
      { doc_as_upsert: false}
    ]
  }
})
```

Where the client is the Elasticsearch client and "my_index" is the index, of course. The result is

```
{
  total: 2,
  failed: 2,
  retry: 0,
  successful: 0,
  noop: 0,
  time: 73,
  bytes: 475,
  aborted: false
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm getting wrong? Similar syntax works great for bulk insert. Just from the docs, it's hard to tell what I'm missing with this.

Comment: it's not clear what your update actually does. You're not using `my_field` at all, i.e. you're probably missing a `doc:{my_field: doc.my_field}` in your logic

Comment: True, I've tried guessing in the dark and adding a doc object. Even though this doesn't cause an error to be thrown or anything, it has no effect. Check out the docs for the JavaScript client (v8.1)! This is exactly what they have. The "doc" I'm assuming - is the "datasource". And it works for insert.

Comment: it works for inserts, but for updates you need to have it in `"doc": { ...}`